# JQuery checkbox on Change not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using the folowing code to select all or one-by-one select and saving checked checkboxes values into a object.

```
$(":checkbox.chbx-manage-select").on("change", function(e) {
    var st_lang_manag = {};

    $(":checkbox.chbx-manage-select").each(function(i,v) {
        st_lang_manag[v.value] = v.checked;
    });
    console.log(st_lang_manag);
});
```

[image]

The code is working fine in Chrome and firefox but in safari 10.0.1 when I select all checkbox it saves false for all selected checkboxes in the object and when I unselect all checkbox it saves true for all unselected checkboxes in the object ( vice versa).

But when I select one by one it works fine.

Comment: I don't see how the code shown could work in any browser. You never set `st_lang_manag` to be an array or object, so you should get an error when you try to reference `st_lang_manag[v.value]`.

Comment: @ nnnnnn I have updated the code.

Comment: The code is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari.

Comment: Can you make an executable stack snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I tried https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/90fj8qao/ in Safari and it works as expected.

Comment: I also works as expected on Safari 9.1.2

Comment: @ Barmar and @ Kazi Masum Billah please check the updated code https://jsfiddle.net/90fj8qao/4/